# Problema no envio de email em PHP

Tags: php, formulário, post

Preciso de ajuda num formulário em `PHP` complexo, pois além de enviar `email` para administradores, envia também para o cliente. O email é em `html` e cria automaticamente um `pdf` através de `html2pdf`.
Então é assim, ele está a funcionar, pois cria o `PDF`, envia o `email` com link para o `PDF`, mas não está a pegar nos valores inseridos no formulário.

Processo do formulário, criação do PDF, envio do email, e um contador:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
?>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
        $email_to = "primeiro@email.com,segundo@email.com";
    $email_client = $_POST['email'];

    $email_subject = "3Compare Booking";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['number']) ||
        !isset($_POST['optionsRadios']))
         {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       


    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $number = $_POST['number']; // required
    $optionsAreas = $_POST['optionsAreas']; // not required
    $optionsRadios = $_POST['optionsRadios']; // not required
    $newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];

}


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= "The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />";
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($number) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$optionsRadios)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$newsletter)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    $datei = fopen("library/countlog.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);
$ref="3COMPAREWLC".$count."-".date('ymd');
$numlink = '3COMPAREWLC'.$count.'-'.date('ymd');
    $email_message ="<body style='background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;'>
<div style='background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;'>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' height='100%' width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' valign='top' style='padding:20px 0 20px 0'>
                <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                <table bgcolor='FFFFFF' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10' border='0' width='650' style='border:1px solid #E0E0E0;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign='top'>
                            <a href='http://super8.pt/3compare/'><img src='http://super8.pt/3compare/library/images/3compare_logo.jpg' alt='3COMPARE'  style='margin-bottom:10px;' border='0'/></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign='top'>
                            <h1 style='font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;'>New Reservation</h1>
                            <p style='font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0;'>A new reservation was made on the website 3COMPARE</p>
                            <p style='border:1px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0; padding:13px 18px; background:#f9f9f9;'>
                               Personal Info <br/>
                               <strong>Reference:</strong> ".clean_string($ref)."<br/>
                                <strong>Name:</strong> ". $_POST['name']."<br/>
                                <strong>Email:</strong> ".$_POST['email']."<br/>
                                <strong>Mobile Number:</strong> ".$_POST['number']."<br/>
                                <strong>Payment Method:</strong> ".$_POST['optionsRadios']."<br/>
                                <strong>Newsletter:</strong> ".$_POST['newsletter']."<p>
                            <p style='font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;'>Laser Hair Loss Therapy:<br/>
30-minute session per week for three months, with 13 sessions in total.</p>
                            <p style='border:1px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0; padding:13px 18px; background:#f9f9f9;'>".$optionsAreas."</p>
                            <p style='font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;'></p>
                            <p style='border:1px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0; padding:13px 18px; background:#f9f9f9;'>
                            <a href='http://super8.pt/3compare/voucher/ticket".$numlink.".pdf'>Click here to download and print your voucher</a>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EAEAEA' align='center' style='background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;'><center><p style='font-size:12px; margin:0;'><strong>3COMPARE</strong></p></center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
@mail($email_client, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
ob_start();
    $num = '3COMPAREWLC'.$count.'-'.date('ymd');
    $nom = $name;
    $date = '2014/07/31';
?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    div.zone { border: none; border-radius: 6mm; background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3mm; font-size: 2.7mm;}
    h1 { padding: 0; margin: 0; color: #DD0000; font-size: 7mm; }
    h2 { padding: 0; margin: 0; color: #222222; font-size: 5mm; position: relative; }
-->
</style>
<page format="100x200" orientation="L" backcolor="#f0a804" style="font: arial;">
    <div style="rotate: 90; position: absolute; width: 100mm; height: 4mm; left: 195mm; top: 0; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; font-size: 2.5mm;">
        This is your e-ticket to present at the Clinic 
    </div>
    <table style="width: 99%;border: none;" cellspacing="4mm" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">
                <div class="zone" style="height: 34mm;position: relative;font-size: 5mm;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; right: 3mm; top: 3mm; text-align: right; font-size: 4mm; ">
                        <b><?php echo $nom; ?></b><br>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; right: 3mm; bottom: 3mm; text-align: right; font-size: 4mm; ">
                        <b>Weight Loss Clinic</b><br>
                        Reference : <b><?php echo $num; ?></b><br>
                        Booked at : <b><?php echo date('d/m/Y à H:i:s'); ?></b><br>
                    </div>
                    <h1>VOUCHER</h1>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Valid until <?php echo $date; ?></b><br>
                    <img src="library/images/3compare_logo.jpg" width="233" height="65" alt="logo" style="margin-top: 3mm; margin-left: 20mm">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%;">
                <div class="zone" style="height: 40mm;vertical-align: middle;text-align: left;">
                    <b><?php echo $_POST['optionsAreas']?></b>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <div class="zone" style="height: 40mm;vertical-align: middle; text-align: justify">
                    <b>Personal Info</b><br>
                                <strong>Name:</strong> <?php echo $_POST['name']?><br/>
                                <strong>Email:</strong> <?php echo $_POST['email']?><br/>
                                <strong>Mobile Number:</strong> <?php echo $_POST['number']?><br/>
                                <strong>Payment Method:</strong> <?php echo $_POST['optionsRadios']?><br/>
                            <p style="font-size:10px; line-height:12px; margin:0 0 8px 0;"><b>Laser Hair Loss Therapy:</b><br/>
30-minute session per week for three months, with 13 sessions in total.</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</page>
<?php
     $content = ob_get_clean();

    // convert
    try
    {
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', 0);
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        $html2pdf->Output('voucher/ticket'.$num.'.pdf','F');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
?>
<!-- include your own success html here -->
<div class="container orange-bg">
        <p><div class="alert alert-success">Thank you <?php echo $_POST['name']?> for booking at 3COMPARE. We will be in touch with you very soon. <a class="btn btn-warning btn-shadow" href="<?php echo 'voucher/ticket'.$num.'.pdf'?>"><strong>Download your Voucher</strong> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></a></div></p>
      </div>
      <?php
/* counter */

//opens countlog.txt to read the number of hits
$datei = fopen("library/countlog.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);
$count=$count + 1 ;

// opens countlog.txt to change new hit number
$datei = fopen("library/countlog.txt","w");
fwrite($datei, $count);
fclose($datei);

?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Formulário:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal marginform" role="form" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="frm1" id="frm1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 white-box wborder-box">
          <?php
            $onearea .= "Order Details <br/>
                                <strong>Duration:</strong> 45 mins<br/>
                                <strong>Employee:</strong> Cristina @ HDC<br/>
                                <strong>SubTotal:</strong> £85.00<br/>
                                <strong>Total</strong>: £85.00<br/>
                                <strong>Valid until</strong>: 2014-07-31<br/>";

    $twoareas .= "Order Details <br/>
                                <strong>Duration:</strong> 45 mins<br/>
                                <strong>Employee:</strong> Cristina @ HDC<br/>
                                <strong>SubTotal:</strong> £165.00<br/>
                                <strong>Total</strong>: £165.00<br/>
                                <strong>Valid until</strong>: 2014-07-31<br/>";
                ?>
            <h5>Order Details</h5>
            <div class="radio-inline areasform">
              <label for="optionsAreas1" name="oa1label" class="control-label">One Area</label>
              <input type="radio" name="optionsAreas" id="optionsAreas1" value="<?php echo ($onearea); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="radio-inline areasform">
            <label for="optionsAreas2" class="control-label">Two Areas</label>
              <input type="radio" name="optionsAreas" id="optionsAreas2" value="<?php echo ($twoareas); ?>">
            </div>
            <p><strong>Cryogenic Lipolysis Therapy</br>45-minute session per week for three months, with 13 sessions in total.</strong></p>

            <div id="hideOneArea">
            <h5>One Area</h5>
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt><small>Duration</small></dt>
            <dd><small>45 mins</small></dd>
            <dt><small>Employee</small></dt>
            <dd><small>Cristina @ HDC</small></dd>
            <dt><small>SUBTOTAL</small></dt>
            <dd><small>£85.00</small></dd>
            <dt><small>TOTAL</small></dt>
            <dd><small>£85.00</small></dd>
            </dl>
            </div>
            <div id="hideTwoAreas">
            <h5>Two Areas</h5>
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt><small>Duration</small></dt>
            <dd><small>45 mins</small></dd>
            <dt><small>Employee</small></dt>
            <dd><small>Cristina @ HDC</small></dd>
            <dt><small>SUBTOTAL</small></dt>
            <dd><small>£165.00</small></dd>
            <dt><small>TOTAL</small></dt>
            <dd><small>£165.00</small></dd>
            </dl>
            </div>

            <p><strong>Payment method:</strong></p>
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Pay At Clinic" checked>Pay At Clinic
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="Other Way" class="hidden">
            </div>
            <p><strong>Available until: 2014-07-31</strong></p>
            <input name="ref" type="hidden" value="<?php $datei = fopen("library/countlog.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);echo "3COMPAREWLC".$count."-".date('ymd');?>">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 white-box wborder-box">
          <h5>Your contact details</h5>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Your full name*</small></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Full Name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small>Your email address*</small></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><small class="redtext">Mobile Number*</small></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="tel" name="number" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 alinharr">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-shadow" value="Send">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      <small class="sizebtn">Click Here to</small></br><strong class="sizebtnlg">Complete Your Order</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
      </div>

      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Yes" id="newsletter" checked> <small>Keep me in the loop about special offers and the latest community news</small> 
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="newsletter" value="No" id="newsletter1">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

O problema está no formulário, pois ele não está a pegar os valores inseridos, logo, envia o email sem os dados.

**UPDATE:**

Já consigo enviar os dados, menos os dados da `OptionsAreas` e não está a enviar `email` para o cliente. Outro problema é que a `OptionsAreas` não está a esconder os valores no formulário. Se seleciono uma área, a outra não deveria aparecer.

Alguém ajuda por favor

Comment: Tente debugar o seu script, se você der um echo $_POST['name'], ele aparece algo ?

Comment: Obrigado. Consigo através de echo $_POST['name'] fazer com que pegasse nos valores à excepção da Options Areas. Continuo sem conseguir enviar email para o cliente

Answer (score 1):

Testei aqui o seu script e funcionou 'perfeitamente', gerou o pdf na pasta voucher, contou a visita para gerar o código do voucher, e gerou os dois e-mails também. Como eu testo localmente no XAMPP, são gerados dois arquivos com os e-mail na pasta mailoutput, indicando assim que funciona, abri os arquivos e estão OK.

Para não deixar dúvida coloquei on-line e também enviou os emails bem como gerou o pdf. Já com relação aos Options, confesso que ainda não entendi sua dúvida.

Será que o [JQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) não resolve seu problema?

E ao invés de utilizar o echo $_POST['nome'], que tal usar o **print_r($_POST)**.

[Faça o teste on-line](http://tarcnux.com.br/stackoverflow_mail_duvida/)